apache-arrow from npm registry to read parquet file from aws s3 bucket
I'm using Typescript.
Reading parquet file using aws-sdk and apache-arrow lib
Parquet file from s3 bucket is of 49KB size
import { tableFromJSON, Table, tableFromIPC } from 'apache-arrow';
...

public static readParquetFile = async (bucket: string, key: string): Promise<Table | null> => {
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();

    try {
      // Fetch the object from S3
      const { Body } = await s3.getObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: key }).promise();

      if (Body) {
        // Read the Parquet file using Apache Arrow
        const table = tableFromIPC(new Uint8Array(Body as Buffer));
        return table;
      } else {
        console.error('Empty file or file not found.');
        return null;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error reading Parquet file:', error);
      return null;
    }
  };

Useage of this function in my lambda code goes like this...
...
try {
      const table = await Utility.readParquetFile(bucketName, fileName);
      if (table) {
        // Convert the table to string content
        const stringContent = table.toString();
        

        // Process content line by line
        const strRecords = stringContent.split('\n');
       

        await Promise.all(
          strRecords.map(async (strRecord: string) => {
            await publishRecord(
              record,
              strRecord, 
              snsTopic,
              snsClient,
              loggingContext
            );
          })
        );
      } else {
        throw new Error('Failed to read Parquet file');
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
     console.error('Error reading Parquet file:', error);
      throw error;
    }
    ...
    ...`

I get this error upon lambda execution : Error reading Parquet file: Error: Expected to read 827474256 metadata bytes, but only read 49256. What is going wrong here? Parquet file is read well using python library though but not with ts lib.
Expecting parquet file to be read well and publish each record to an SNS topic
